# How to add a field in one text input by clicking a button in PySimpleGUI?

Tags: python, button, input, calculator, pysimplegui

Dears,

I'm new in using Stackoverflow & PySimpleGUI... I want add one functionality in my project using PySimpleGUI, So that when I click in one Button, it will insert a text in another Text Field, it's similar principle as creating calculator , but the only difference I need to input some letter from my keyboard too. To make things more clear, I'm having some Special characters which can't be inserted from key board in that text field , So that I use PySimpleGUI to help me on that :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update the text of the `Input` element with the new characters into the `Input` element.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('DarkBlue3')

words = "This is a book".split(' ')
layout = [
    [sg.Input(key='-IN-')],
    [sg.Push()] + [sg.Button(word, size=4) for word in words],
]
window = sg.Window("Title", layout, finalize=True)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event in words:
        text = values['-IN-'].strip()
        text = text + (' ' if text else '') +event
        window['-IN-'].update(text)

window.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jason Yang, Is it possible to do the same by spliting letters from word instead of words? I want to have an input as a combination of special characters, so that I can have each time one letter at a a time. Thanks in advance

Comment: It's fixed by eliminating the space between words and replace it by hiphen. Great JOB Thx

Comment: To split letters from a string, call `list(string)`.

Comment: Great!! @Jason, How to keep those buttons to the right? I tried using : "element_justification='r'  ", Unfortunately didn't help.

Comment: Updated as above.

Comment: EXcellent JOB Jason...Thanks for your help.