# How to push buttons to the right PySimpleGUI?

Tags: button, layout, split, push, pysimplegui

Dears,

Could you please help to share ideas on how to push Buttons to the right?
Knowing that I go through the forum and I find cases where no condition is set and this can be done using differents ways, like sg.push(), Sg.column(), justifications="right", but in my case bottouns are created based on one string as follows :

words= "S-C-I-E-N-C-E".split('-')

layout = [
[sg.Button(word, size=2) for word in words], => What to add in this line to make Buttons push to the right ?

Thanks in avdance

Comment: It was fixed in another Topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74154603/how-to-add-a-field-in-one-text-input-by-clicking-a-button-in-pysimplegui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out sg.Push in the [documentation](https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/call%20reference/#push-element-alias-include-p-and-stretch). You will need something to the left for the push to push against. Perhaps an empty text column followed by push followed by the buttons.

For example:

```
[sg.Text(new_query,key='-QUERYNAME-'),
 sg.Push(),
 sg.Button(run_event,tooltip='Run (F5)')]
```

Gives me this:
[image]

You probably want something like:

```
layout = [sg.Text(''), sg.Push(), [sg.Button(word, size=2) for word in words]]
```

Comment: t's working as expected as follows :
    [sg.Push()] + [sg.Button(word, size=2) for word in words],